# Ошибка при создании секции в вкладке magento

Tags: php, magento

Сделал (`Magento 1.9`) в System -> Configuration -> Services новую секцию таким образом:

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <service translate="label" module="core">
            <label>Services</label>
            <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
        </service>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <brain_caliber translate="label">
            <label>Caliber API</label>
            <tab>service</tab>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

            <groups>
                <brain_caliber_group translate="label">
                    <label>Configuration Caliber</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

                    <fields>
                        <brain_caliber_password translate="password">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <comment>Password for caliber service</comment>
                            <frontend_type>password</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </brain_caliber_password>
                        <hexbrain_caliber_email translate="label">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <comment>Email for caliber service</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-email</validate>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </brain_caliber_email>

                    </fields>
                </brain_caliber_group>
            </groups>
        </brain_caliber>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Новая секция появляется в вкладке `Services` но при нажатии - ошибка:

> 404 Error Page not found.

**В чем может быть проблема? Или я что-то не так сделал?**

Comment: эмм а разлогиниться и залогиниться в админку снова не забыл?

Comment: @Naumov, нет не забыл, даже `rm -rf var/session/*` сделал! 
Долго думал что не так - и вспомнил, что в `config.xml` не внес секцию `<acl>`! Дописал ее и начало работать!

Comment: Да есть такое но я всегда её ишу уже на автомате

Comment: @Naumov,ну теперь тоже постараюсь привыкнуть на автомате писать